# Bidirectional link in Realm database

Tags: android, realm

I want to access the field in parent table from child table.

```
public class Product extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("location")
    private String locationInStore;

     @SerializedName("tags")
    private RealmList<Tag> productTags;
}
```

and

```
public class Tag extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String name;
    }
}
```

Now I have to search for the name in tag table and then I have to show the name that has matched the search and location of that tag.

```
  RealmResults<Tag> name = mRealm.where(Tag.class).contains("name", tag, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
```

But this gives me only tag name, how can I access its location and other properties.

I also tried

```
 List<RealmResults<Product>> results = new ArrayList<>();

 results.add(mRealm.where(Product.class).contains("productTags.name", tag, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll());
```

Above query returns me the product object but this product object contain the tag array not the one which has matched the search.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `List<RealmResults<Product>> results = new ArrayList<>();` but why?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce because my complete query is
          results.add(mRealm.where(Product.class).equalTo("productTags.name", tag, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll());


            results.add(mRealm.where(Product.class).beginsWith("productTags.name", tag, Case.INSENSITIVE).notEqualTo("productTags.name", tag, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll());
            results.add(mRealm.where(Product.class).contains("productTags.name", tag, Case.INSENSITIVE).not().beginsWith("productTags.name", tag, Case.INSENSITIVE).notEqualTo("productTags.name", tag, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll());

Comment: Your question confuses me.  You have Product *->1 Tag.  That means that any Product, with its location, is likely to be associated with multiple Tags.  No matter what you do, when you select a Product, it is likely to be associated with Tags that have several different names.  The query you show will return all of the Products that have at least one Tag, whose name is whatever `tag` is.  It is the one that matches the search.  It seems quite likely that it will also be associated with other Tags and that those tags will have different names.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea, why *not the one of array has no matched the search*, is a `Case.INSENSITIVE` search. Be carefull using this because of functionality have limitations:

> Sorting and case insensitive string matches in queries are only supported for character sets in ‘Latin Basic’, ‘Latin Supplement’, ‘Latin Extended A’, ‘Latin Extended B’ (UTF-8 range 0-591). Moreover, sorting is done so capital and non-capital letters are sorted togther unlike what standard libraries do. That means that '- !"#0&()*,./:;?_+<=>123aAbBcCxXyYzZ is the actual sorting order in Realm. In addition, setting the case insensitive flag in queries when using equalTo(), notEqualTo(), contains(), endsWith(), beginsWith() or like() will only work on characters from the English locale.

Read more about these limitations [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/581)